# How to set a folder as the download location folder

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a url link that once you click on it, a txt file automatically downloads but I want to set the folder where this txt file downloads to be in the below desktop folder "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Folder"

The below link opens the URL in a browser and downloads the file automatically to the "Downloads" folder as I am using Chrome. I would like to set the download folder via sql vb.net.

Below are the queries I tried but only the first one worked but downloaded to "Downloads" folder (very simple):

```
Private Sub UpdateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateBtn.Click

  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("URL")

End Sub
```

I also tried the below code but it gave me an error that I have to specify a file name - but I don't want it to work that way:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("URL", "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Folder", "", "", False, 500, True)
```

Another query I tested but nothing happened:

```
Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
Dim Path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("URL"), Path)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all !

Marc

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Wouldn't this be a security concern if your webpage could decide where to download files onto my computer? If this is possible, why isn't everyone doing this to plant RATs? I understand that this isn't a webpage, but the download is handled by a webbrowser.

Comment: Thanks Josiah, it's an application I am creating for myself.. that would be disappointing if it couldn't work.. should try the WebClient or HttpWebRequest as keyboardP mentioned... humm have to figure that out now, Thanks!

Comment: @MarcChemali - I've added an example of how you could use the WebClient to do this.

Comment: Just avoid the browser and you can still do this. Although I know nothing of VB.net so someone else will have to help with that like @keyboardP says he has.

Comment: @keyboardP thanks for the help, I will definitely try your code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, the question should've been more clear on that. keyboardP is right. I have deleted my answer as it supposed a download via a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a text file you could use the `WebClient` to download it straight from your app and then have your app write it out to the user's hard drive (wherever you have permission of course).

```
Dim wc As New WebClient()
AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf wc_DownloadStringCompleted   
wc.DownloadStringAsync("URL")

Private Shared Sub wc_DownloadStringCompleted(sender As Object, e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)

'add any error handling code
'...

File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Folder\MyFile.txt", e.Result)

End Sub
```